# install bootstrap4 for yii2 default template

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, yii2

Tried to install bootstrap4 for yii2 basic template using several guides. Seems It didn't go as intended.

What I did:

1) cmd: `composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic` // install yii2

Result: yii2 basic template works using bootstrap3

2.1) cmd: `cd yii2-app-basic` // go to yii2 folder

2.2) cmd: `composer require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4` // install bootstrap4 for yii2

2.3) Updated dependencies in **\assets\AppAsset.php**:

```
public $depends = [
    'yii\web\YiiAsset',
    'yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapAsset',
];
```

Result: two bootstrap `<link>`s in `<head>` (bootstrap3 + bootstrap4). Navbar looks bad:
[image: Navbar looks bad]

3) Updated **\views\layouts\main.php**:

```
use yii\bootstrap4\Nav;
use yii\bootstrap4\NavBar;
```

Result: small-screen navbar version without button icon (on all screen sizes):
[image: small-screen version]

4) cmd: `composer remove yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap` // remove bootstrap3

Result: "Class 'yii\bootstrap\Widget' not found"

5) Changed "yii\bootstrap\" to "yii\bootstrap4\" for all *.php files in /yii2-app-basic/

Result: same as (3)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that problem with navbar was because of this:

```
NavBar::begin([
    'brandLabel' => Yii::$app->name,
    'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top', // THIS LINE
    ],
]);
```

It forced navbar to render as `<nav id="w0" class="navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar">` while bootstrap4 navbar needs `navbar-expand` and color scheme class eg. `navbar-dark`

So we can:

1) delete mentioned `'class'` line >> navbar will render as `<nav id="w0" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">`

2) or update it: `'class' => 'fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark',`

Same goes for button classes, etc... Just need to change it to bootstrap4 variation.

Comment: to align navbar items right (like in bootstrap3 default template) you can use `'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav ml-auto'],` in `Nav::widget`

Answer (score 4):

Most of widgets in default views of yii2 projects use yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset (bootstrap 3).
Do not expect it magically toggle when you call yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapAsset.

Your step 2.3 is just adds bootstrap 4 to all other libraries you call by using widgets.

What you can do:

1) make sure you are calling yii\bootstrap4\ widgets and not calling yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset or any assets that depends on this class. Examples:

- use yii\bootstrap4\Html;
- use yii\bootstrap4\Modal;
- use yii\bootstrap4\Tabs;
- use yii\bootstrap4\ActiveForm;

2) Remember that bootstrap 4 have different classes than bootstrap 3. So if you will apply it to default views it highly likely will break because it does not have some classes from other version, or js acting differently.

Answer (score 0):

Probably in `Widgets` folder at the root of project, in `Alert.php` file you need to change :

```
class Alert extends \yii\bootstrap\Widget
```

to

```
class Alert extends \yii\bootstrap4\Widget
```